# Show created and last edited date in custom date field automatically

Tags: workflow, custom-field, date

I have followed instructions from this other stack exchange [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41482/how-to-track-the-creation-and-last-edited-date-of-a-custom-field-best-practice) to set/ show note modified date to the day it was changed or new.

It does work fine but as you can see from the print screen it is showing on the 'side' of the note date field on the salesforce form--- I need it to be in the actual field!

[image]

Comment: the example will only fill the data after saving the record (that is the moment workflow rules are triggered. So try saving and the date will be filled in. The date shown above is just the default view for any date field in edit mode. It shows today's date by default.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to change formula field instead of workflow field update.

if yes. just add below formula.

LastModifiedDate-CreatedDate